# Proof involving double integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove that

[image]

Hint: Recall the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and exploit it.

Comment: Share your doubts and what you have tried so far. It would be much easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

Chainging the order of integration on the LHS,

$$\int_a^bdx\int_x^bdyf(x)f(y)=\int_a^bdy\int_a^ydxf(x)f(y)\\
=\int_a^bdx\int_a^xdyf(y)f(x)$$

In the second line above, we've simply swapped the dummy variables $x$ and $y$.

Looking at the RHS,

$$\left(\int_a^bdxf(x)\right)^2=\left(\int_a^bdxf(x)\right)\left(\int_a^bdyf(y)\right)\\
=\int_a^bdx\int_a^bdyf(x)f(y)\\
=\int_a^bdx\left(\int_a^xdyf(y)f(x)+\int_x^bdyf(y)f(x)\right).$$

But we've already shown above that the two integrals in parentheses are equal, so their sum equals twice one of the integrals, giving the desired identity.